# unable to trigger job in concourse

Tags: concourse

I was new to concourse, and set up the environment in my centos7.6 like below.

```
$ wget https://concourse-ci.org/docker-compose.yml
$ docker-compose up -d
Then login by `fly --target example login --team-name main --concourse-url  http://192.168.77.140:8080/ -u test -p test`
```

I can see below.

```
[root@centostest ~]# fly targets
name     url                         team  expiry
example  http://192.168.77.140:8080  main  Sun, 16 Jun 2019 02:23:48 UTC
```

I used below yaml.xml named with **2.yaml**

```
---
resources:
- name: my-git-repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://github.com/ruanbekker/concourse-test
    branch: basic-helloworld

jobs:
- name: hello-world-job
  public: true
  plan:
  - get: my-git-repo
  - task: task_print-hello-world
    file: my-git-repo/ci/task-hello-world.yml
```

Then I run below commands step by step.

```
fly -t example sp -c 2.yaml -p pipeline-01
fly -t example up -p pipeline-01
fly -t example tj -j pipeline-01/hello-world-job --watch
```

But i just hang on there , no useful response like below.

```
[root@centostest ~]# fly -t example tj -j pipeline-01/hello-world-job --watch
started pipeline-01/hello-world-job #3
```

Theoretically， it should print something like below.

```
Cloning into '/tmp/build/get'...
Fetching HEAD
292c84b change task name
initializing
running echo hello world
hello world
succeeded
```

Where I did wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Concourse!

One thing that can be confusing when starting with Concourse is understanding *when* Concourse detects that the pipeline has changed and what happens if the pipeline is one file or multiple files.

Your pipeline (as the majority of real-world pipelines) is "nested": main pipeline file `2.yaml` refers to a task file named `my-git-repo/ci/task-hello-world.yml`

What sets Concourse apart from other CI systems is that:

1. the main pipeline file (`2.yaml`) can reside everywhere, also in a different repository.
2. Due to 1, Concourse is unable to detect a change to the main pipeline file, you have to tell Concourse that the file has changed, either with `fly set-pipeline` or with automatic means such as the concourse-pipeline-resource.

So the following errors happen often:

- Changing the main pipeline file, committing and pushing, and expecting Concourse to pick up the change. Missing: you have to do `fly set-pipeline`
- Once doing `fly set-pipeline` becomes second nature, you can stumble upon the opposite error: Change both the main pipeline file and the nested task file, not pushing, doing set-pipeline. In this case, the only changes picked up by Concourse will be the ones to the main pipeline file, not to the task file. Missing: commit and push.

From the description of your problem, I have the feeling that it is a mixture of the gotchas I mentioned.